# Intermittent BeautifulSoup with Amazon Book ISBN

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to gather some information about some books available on Amazon and I am having a weird glitch error that I can't understand. At first I thought it was Amazon blocking my connection but then I noticed the request has a "200 OK" and it had the real HTML content of the corresponding page.

Let's take for example this book: https://www.amazon.co.uk/All-Rage-Cara-Hunter/dp/0241985110

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}

url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/All-Rage-Cara-Hunter/dp/0241985110/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2PPCQEJD706VY&dchild=1&keywords=books+bestsellers+2020+paperback&qid=1598132071&sprefix=book%2Caps%2C234&sr=8-1'

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, features="lxml")

price = {}

if soup.select("#buyBoxInner > ul > li > span > .a-text-strike") != []:
    price["regular_price"] = float(
        soup.select("#buyBoxInner > ul > li > span > .a-text-strike")[0].string[1:].replace(",", "."))
    price["promo_price"] = float(soup.select(".offer-price")[0].string[1:].replace(",", "."))
else:
    price["regular_price"] = float(soup.select(".offer-price")[0].string[1:].replace(",", "."))
price["currency"] = soup.select(".offer-price")[0].string[0]
```

This part works fine and I can have the regular price and a promo price (if exists), and even the currency. But when I do this:

```
isbn = soup.select("td.bucket > .content > ul > li")[4].contents[1].string.strip().replace("-", "")
```

I get "IndexError: list index out of range". But if I debug the code, the content is actually there!

Is this a bug of BeautifulSoup? Is the request response too long?

Comment: Is ```soup.select("td.bucket > .content > ul > li")[4]``` throwing the error or ```contents[1]```?

Comment: @sintribu ```soup.select("td.bucket > .content > ul > li")[4]```

Comment: I don't know how this helps you, but when I run this code, it runs fine for me.  I just had to add a couple of imports at the top and a `print(isbn)` at the bottom, and I get an output of `9780241985113`

Comment: Try to run it multiple times just to test it out

Comment: It works for me sometimes but not others. Web scraping is a weird thing ???

Comment: Wow!  Same here.  Works for me about 3 times out of 4.

Comment: @sintribu Exactly! That's what I'm getting! How can I make sure this won't happen? I've tried to run the request again a create the "soup" variable again until reaching something, but no luck.

Comment: Sorry maybe I misunderstood. It is working some of the time for you?

Comment: The more i insist, the less I get

Comment: @MiguelSantana if this IS intermittent for you, you should make that clear in your question, as it makes all the difference in the world as to how someone will approach the issue. - I would suggest that the word "intermittent" be in the title.

Comment: I would take the `"[4].contents[1].string.strip().replace("-", "")` part out of the initial select 1 liner.  Then you can display the value and see what is being returned on occasion.  The select could be empty or the data could be different and you may have to parse in a way more driven by content than hardcoded indices.  You can’t tell here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that Amazon returns two version of the page. One where's `<td class="bucket">` and one where are several `<span>` tags. This script tries to extract ISBN from both of them:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}

url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/All-Rage-Cara-Hunter/dp/0241985110'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, features="lxml")

isbn_10 = soup.select_one('span.a-text-bold:contains("ISBN-10"), b:contains("ISBN-10")').find_parent().text
isbn_13 = soup.select_one('span.a-text-bold:contains("ISBN-13"), b:contains("ISBN-13")').find_parent().text

print(isbn_10.split(':')[-1].strip())
print(isbn_13.split(':')[-1].strip())
```

Prints:

```
0241985110
978-0241985113
```

Comment: Wow.  Nice catch, and excellent solution.  You obviously know your Soup.  Do you have any idea WHY Amazon would be returning two different pages?  I wonder if it's a matter of a roll-out of a new version of the page that didn't (or hasn't yet) make it to all of the servers.

Comment: @Steve Maybe they A/B testing two versions of same page, or different version of server software...or maybe they want to make it harder for bots to scrape the information.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thanks a lot! It worked. Just one more question. Are the price selectors ok? I've run it with a list of 50+ URL's and it gave the same error, but for the price. What do you think?

Comment: @MiguelSantana I think you're getting Captcha page from the server. After several requests I started to get it too.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Do you think if I create a requests.session I can bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had an explanation of the problem but you a solution would be to wrap your code in a function like so:

```
def scrape():
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}

    url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/All-Rage-Cara-Hunter/dp/0241985110/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2PPCQEJD706VY&dchild=1&keywords=books+bestsellers+2020+paperback&qid=1598132071&sprefix=book%2Caps%2C234&sr=8-1'

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, features="lxml")

    price = {}

    if soup.select("#buyBoxInner > ul > li > span > .a-text-strike") != []:
        price["regular_price"] = float(
            soup.select("#buyBoxInner > ul > li > span > .a-text-strike")[0].string[1:].replace(",", "."))
        price["promo_price"] = float(soup.select(".offer-price")[0].string[1:].replace(",", "."))
    else:
        price["regular_price"] = float(soup.select(".offer-price")[0].string[1:].replace(",", "."))
    price["currency"] = soup.select(".offer-price")[0].string[0]


    #ADD THIS FEATURE TO YOUR CODE
    isbn = soup.select("td.bucket > .content > ul > li")
    if not isbn:
        scrape()


    isbn = isbn[4].contents[1].string.strip().replace("-", "")
```

Then if it fails it will just call itself again. You might want to refactor it so it only makes the request once.

Comment: Thanks for your input but I've actually tried something like that and it stays the same. It keeps failing sometimes.